# R Generate random binary vector of fixed length with fixed sum

Tags: r, random

Quick question: In R, how to generate a random binary vector of fixed length with fixed sum.

For example:

I want a binary vector of length 100 that sum up to 15.

Thanks!

Comment: Numerous ways, including `sample(c(rep(1,15),rep(0,85)))`

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function for this:

```
rand_binary <- function(n,k){
  v <- numeric(n)
  v[sample(seq_along(v),k)] <- 1
  v
}
```

And then `rand_binary(100,15)` evaluates to a randomly chosen vector consisting of 85 0s and 15 1s.

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like below

```
replace(rep(0, 100), sample(100, 15), 1)
```